# How do I know if a blank CD-R is LightScribe compatible?

Tags: dvd-burning, cd, lightscribe

I have a blank CD-R. Its just white, without any writings and i don't have it's box.

How to know if i can use LightScribe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightscribe disks have the Lightscribe logo on the inner hub area of a Lightscribe disk.

http://www.google.com/search?q=lightscribe+logo&biw=640&bih=400&tbm=isch&oq=lightscribe+logo&gs_l=img.12..0.51581.62430.0.63620.23.21.0.2.2.0.269.2598.3j16j2.21.0....0...1ac.1.34.img..13.10.877.bguOZR5Zv3Y

Answer (score 2):

The LightScribe Dvd's I had were all more of a tan color than a white.

LightScribe Compatible
[image: LightScribe Compatible]

vs

Thermal printer Compatible
[image: Thermal printer Compatible]

Comment: To add to that, in this [link](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-burn-labels-back-your-discs-cds-dvds) it says "They have one color and their surface seems slightly different than that of normal discs." If you google images for them, they are almost always more yellow/tan.